# RxJs - how to make observable behave like queue

Tags: rxjs, queue, rxjs6

I'm trying to achieve next:

```
private beginTransaction(): Observable() {
  ..
}

private test(): void {
  this.beginTransaction().subscribe((): void => {
    this.commitTransaction();
  });

  this.beginTransaction().subscribe((): void => {
     this.commitTransaction();
  });
}
```

**beginTransaction can be called concurrently, but should delay the observable until first or only one beginTransaction finished.**

**In order words: Only one transaction can be in progress at any time.**

What have I tried:

```
private transactionInProgress: boolean = false;
private canBeginTransaction: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

private bla3(): void {

  this.beginTransaction().subscribe((): void => {
    console.log('beginTransaction 1');
    this.commitTransaction();
  });

  this.beginTransaction().subscribe((): void => {
    console.log('beginTransaction 2');
    this.commitTransaction();
  });

  this.beginTransaction().subscribe((): void => {
    console.log('beginTransaction 3');
    this.commitTransaction();
  });
}

private commitTransaction(): void {
  this.transactionInProgress = false;
  this.canBeginTransaction.next();
}

private beginTransaction(): Observable<void> {

  if(this.transactionInProgress) {
    return of(undefined)
    .pipe(
      skipUntil(this.canBeginTransaction),
      tap((): void => {
        console.log('begin transaction');
      })
    );
  }
  this.transactionInProgress = true;
  return of(undefined);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've asked about is pretty vague and general. Without a doubt, a more constrained scenario could probably look a whole lot simpler.

Regardless, here I create a pipeline that only lets `transaction(): Observable` be subscribed to once at a time.

Here's how that might look:

```js
/****
 * Represents what each transaction does. Isn't concerned about
 * order/timing/'transactionInProgress' or anything like that.
 * 
 * Here is a fake transaction that just takes 3-5 seconds to emit
 * the string: `Hello ${name}`
 ****/
function transaction(args): Observable<string> {
  const name = args?.message;
  const duration = 3000 + (Math.random() * 2000);
  return of("Hello").pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log("starting transaction")),
    switchMap(v => timer(duration).pipe(
      map(_ => `${v} ${name}`)
    )),
    tap(_ => console.log("Ending transation"))
  );
}

// Track transactions
let currentTransactionId = 0;
// Start transactions
const transactionSubj = new Subject<any>();
// Perform transaction: concatMap ensures we only start a new one if 
// there isn't a current transaction underway
const transaction$ = transactionSubj.pipe(
  concatMap(({id, args}) => transaction(args).pipe(
    map(payload => ({id, payload}))
  )),
  shareReplay(1)
);

/****
 * Begin a new transaction, we give it an ID since transactions are
 * "hot" and we don't want to return the wrong (earlier) transactions,
 * just the current one started with this call.
 ****/
function beginTransaction(args): Observable<any> {
  return defer(() => {
    const currentId = currentTransactionId++;
    transactionSubj.next({id: currentId, args});
    return transaction$.pipe(
      first(({id}) => id === currentId),
      map(({payload}) => payload)
    );
  })
}

// Queue up 3 transactions, each one will wait for the previous 
// one to complete before it will begin.
beginTransaction({message: "Dave"}).subscribe(console.log);
beginTransaction({message: "Tom"}).subscribe(console.log);
beginTransaction({message: "Tim"}).subscribe(console.log);
```

#### Asynchronous Transactions

The current setup requires transactions to be asynchronous, or you risk losing the first one. The workaround for that is not simple, so I've built an operator that subscribes, then calls a function as soon as possible after that.

Here it is:

```js
function initialize<T>(fn: () => void): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return s => new Observable(observer => {
    const bindOn = name => observer[name].bind(observer);
    const sub = s.subscribe({
      next: bindOn("next"),
      error: bindOn("error"),
      complete: bindOn("complete")
    });
    fn();
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => sub.unsubscribe
    };
  });
}
```

and here it is in use:

```js
function beginTransaction(args): Observable<any> {
  return defer(() => {
    const currentId = currentTransactionId++;
    return transaction$.pipe(
      initialize(() => transactionSubj.next({id: currentId, args})),
      first(({id}) => id === currentId),
      map(({payload}) => payload)
    );
  })
}
```

#### Aside: Why Use `defer`?

Consider re-writting beginTransaction:

```js
function beginTransaction(args): Observable<any> {
  const currentId = currentTransactionId++;
  return transaction$.pipe(
    initialize(() => transactionSubj.next({id: currentId, args})),
    first(({id}) => id === currentId),
    map(({payload}) => payload)
  );
}
```

In this case, the ID is set at the moment you invoke `beginTransaction`.

```js
// The ID is set here, but it won't be used until subscribed
const preppedTransaction = beginTransaction({message: "Dave"});

// 10 seconds later, that ID gets used.
setTimeout(
  () => preppedTransaction.subscribe(console.log),
  10000
);
```

If `transactionSubj.next` is called without the initialize operator, then this problem gets even worse as `transactionSubj.next` would also get called 10 seconds before the observable is subscribed to (You're sure to miss the output)

**The problems continue:**

What if you want to subscribe to the same observable twice?

```js
const preppedTransaction = beginTransaction({message: "Dave"});
preppedTransaction.subscribe(
  value => console.log("First Subscribe: ", value)
);
preppedTransaction.subscribe(
  value => console.log("Second Subscribe: ", value)
);
```

I would expect the output to be:

```html
First Subscribe: Hello Dave
Second Subscribe: Hello Dave
```

Instead, you get

```html
First Subscribe: Hello Dave
First Subscribe: Hello Dave
Second Subscribe: Hello Dave
Second Subscribe: Hello Dave
```

Because you don't get a new ID on subscribing, the two subscriptions **share** one ID. `defer` fixes this problem by not assigning an id until subscription. This becomes seriously important when managing errors in streams (letting you re-try an observable after it errors).

Comment: The only problem is because `transactionSubj.next({id: currentId, args});` is called before ` return transaction$.pipe(`, the first beginTransaction is ignored. Thanks for comments. One more thing I simplified your code wothout `defer()`, `switchMap`. The main point here is that `next` enqeues observable and because concatMap does things in order (waits for each one to complete) with combination of shareReplay it works. Without `shareReplay` each beginTransaction has its own concatMap and not shared, and it doesn't work.

Comment: When I ran this code, it worked - but hey, whatever you need to change. Also, removing the defer doesn't simplify the code, it breaks it. Without defer you must subscribe the same moment that you invoke `beginTransaction` if you don't, you have a race condition and you'll likely get bad/no results.

Comment: @broadband I've added a section that deals with the problem of missing the first value

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood the problem right, but it looks to me as `concatMap` is the operator you are looking for.

An example could be the following

```
const transactionTriggers$ = from([
  't1', 't2', 't3'
])

function processTransation(trigger: string) {
  console.log(`Start processing transation triggered by ${trigger}`)
  // do whatever needs to be done and then return an Observable
  console.log(`Transation triggered by ${trigger} processing ......`)
  return of(`Transation triggered by ${trigger} processed`)
}

transactionTriggers$.pipe(
  concatMap(trigger => processTransation(trigger)),
  tap(console.log)
).subscribe()
```

You basically start from a stream of events, where each event is supposed to trigger the processing of the transaction.

Then you use `processTransaction` function to do whatever you have to do to process a transaction. `processTransactio` needs to return an Observable which emits the result of the processing when the transaction has been processed and then completes.

Then in the pipe you can use `tap` to do further stuff with the result of the processing, if required.

You can try the code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jicwcu?file=index.ts).